# What's different between these 2 partial function objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, partial-application

### Precondition

I have these definitions:

```py
def add(x,y): return (lambda x,y: x+y)(x,y)
def call(f,x,y): return f(x,y)
```

and these `import` aliases:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool as P;
from functools import partial as p;
```

Then I run this:

```py
P(2).map(p(add,1),[2,3])
```

I can get a result: `[3, 4]`

**But if I run this**:

```py
P(2).map(p(p(call,lambda x,y: x+y),1),[2,3])
```

it produces an error message.

- In Python version `2.7.5`:

  ```
  Exception in thread Thread-8:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 812, in __bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 765, in run
      self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
      put(task)
  PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
  ```

  (and then I have to press `^Z` then `kill %1` to close it)
- In Python version `3.6.8`:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
      return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
      raise self._value
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
      put(task)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 210, in send
      self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
      cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7f25b741cd90>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
  ```

  (better than python2: the REPL will give me the `>>>` again ...)

I've tried these, both are okay:

- run: `p(add,1)(3)` , get: `4`
- run: `p(p(call,lambda x,y: x+y),1)(3)` , get: `4`

### Doubt

Now, I have my question:

I think they are *same* thing:

- `(x,y) -> (lambda x,y: x+y)(x,y)`
- `partial((f,x,y) -> f(x,y) , lambda x,y: x+y)`

Clearly they are *in fact different*. But **how**, and **why**?

Comment: While using multiprocessing, you cannot use the internal / nested functions because pickling does not support internal function objects. In first case, `p(add,1)` is evaluated to callable, and that is correct. In 2nd case,  `p(p(call,lambda x,y: x+y),1)` returns a partial, not a fully callable function, so pickle tries to transport it as object containing a function as property. It fails.

Answer (score 0):

A `lambda` function is an unnamed function. `multiprocessing` operates by [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), and that serializes functions by storing their name, e.g. `builtins.len`:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(len)
b'\x80\x04\x95\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x03len\x94\x93\x94.'
```

So when pickling a function built by lambda, the name lookup fails:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(lambda x: len(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7fda31df4280>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

So the two functions have the same call behaviour, but not the same characteristics.

Comment: I've tried to make a lambda like a named function by use partial, then fail. I wans to define a named function by a lambda, not by `def`. Use some function in default library in python2 is better for me ... How can?